# Oracle SQL: Alternative to aggregate large texts (when exceeding Listagg limit)

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate, string-concatenation, listagg

I have a simple Select query that aggregates one column containing large texts. 
The following worked for me with small texts but **I am now exceeding the Listagg character limit** (4000 bytes ?).

I am very new to Oracle and couldn't find a proper solution for this online that I could apply here.

Can someone tell me the best alternative to this ?

**My Query (simplified):**

```
SELECT
    m.S_ID AS SID
    , LISTAGG
    (
        'ITEM NO.: ' || m.ITEM || 
        ' -nl-ARTICLE: ' || a.ARTICLE || 
        ' -nl-NET: ' || m.NET || 
        ' -nl-TAX: ' || NVL(m.TAX, 0) || 
        ' -nl-GROSS: ' || (m.NET + m.TAX),
        ' -nl--nl-'
    ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY m.S_ID) AS Details
    /* ... */
FROM 
    myTable m
/* ... */
```

Many thanks for any help with this,
Mike

Comment: If 32k is enough then just set `MAX_STRING_SIZE` to `extended`: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C.htm#REFRN10321

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks for this. 32k would be enough as I am only expecting up to 10k characters for max items but I cannot make any changes to the db or general SQL settings in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of possible method.

```
select xmlagg(xmlelement(xxx,'ITEM NO.: ' || m.ITEM || 
        ' -nl-ARTICLE: ' || a.ARTICLE || 
        ' -nl-NET: ' || m.NET || 
        ' -nl-TAX: ' || NVL(m.TAX, 0) || 
        ' -nl-GROSS: ' || (m.NET + m.TAX),
        ' -nl--nl-'||',<-separator').extract('//text()') order m.S_ID).getClobval() from mytable
group by ...
```

2nd method.
oracle allows to creat own aggregation function [user defined aggregation function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e10765/aggr_functions.htm#ADDCI2120)

Comment: Thanks so much for this ! Could you explain it a little since I am very new to Oracle so that I can apply it properly ? Does this have no character limit (talking about maybe up to 10000 characters) ?

Comment: Here you have limit up to 4gb. if you remove .extract('//text()') from code you will see normal xml.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will accept this and really like the approach. Could you maybe just add one or two sentences to explain the purpose of "xxx" and ".getClobval" ?

Comment: Also, am I right that it should read ORDER BY instead of ORDER ? :)

Comment: yes should be `ordere by` ,
`xmlagg` is function to aggregate `xmltype` and it accepts only `xmltype`.
`xmlelement(xxx,'somthing')` creates `<xxx>somthing</xxx>`.
`xmlelement(xxx,'something').extract('//text()')` return only 'something' but data type of this element is not string it is xmltype. And expression can be used in `xmlagg`.

Comment: Lukasiewicz: Sorry for the late response. This is great. Thanks a lot for the help and the explanations.